# Subsetting Categorical Covariate of Regression in R

Tags: r, regression, subset, survival-analysis

I am attempting to subset a categorical covariate entitled "Public" that has two levels (0 and 1) within my regression model. I would like to look at how this covariate influences my regression curves' mean and dispersion values by subsetting when model to "1". Unfortunately I am getting an error that says:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

My data is in a dataframe entitled "erad.surv" and looks as such:

```
    Surv(Erad_Time, Event)        Dist Public (weights)
1                       12 -0.51385627      1         1
2                      39+  0.65870948      1         1
3                      39+  0.47563451      0         1
4                      39+  0.73255621      1         1
5                      39+  0.32500333      1         1
6                      39+ -0.60323102      1         1
7                       31  0.60391220      1         1
```

Finally, my regression model is the one provided below. I've also tried seemingly every other combination of the "subset" command to no avail.

```
model.Public <- flexsurvreg(formula = Surv(Erad_Time, Event) ~ Dist + Public, data = erad.surv, subset = (Public == "1"), dist=ig)
```

Any thoughts or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: With your current code, you would need to remove `Public` from the predictors: `formula = Surv(Erad_Time, Event) ~ Dist`. It doesn't really make sense to estimate the effect of a variable that's constant. But it's not 100% clear whether you want to estimate the effect from the public-only data, or use the original model that was fit to the full data and *predict* the effects when `Public == 1`.

Comment: @Marius, thanks for commenting. I was hoping to do the latter: use the original model that was fit to the full data and predict the effects when `Public ==1`.